# Проблема при скролле Recyclerview

Tags: android, recyclerview

Возникла у меня задачка в списке при клике на конкретный текст изменить его свойства, допустим, размер шрифта. Сам список пашет нормально, все отображается, и даже при клике на заголовок меняется размер его шрифта. Но вот при скролле происходит какой то хаос, без кликов начинает уменьшаться размер шрифта, притом происходит все это как то спонтанно.

Вот сам код где реализую клик:

```
public class ListRowViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


protected TextView title;
protected TextView text;
protected TextView autor;
protected RelativeLayout relLayour;
private ChangeSize changeSize;

public ListRowViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);
    changeSize = new ChangeSize();
    this.title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    this.title.setOnClickListener(changeSize);
    this.text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    this.autor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.autor);
    this.relLayour = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relLayour);
    itemView.setClickable(true);
}



private class ChangeSize implements View.OnClickListener {


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        title.setTextSize(10);

    }
}
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: **ChangeSiza** зачёт! А все проблему потому, что применяете сами не знаете что и не знаете зачем

Comment: Почитайте нормальный пример и всё станет работать! http://javatechig.com/android/android-recyclerview-example

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте про механизм переиспользования view в Recyclerview ну или в ListView он там аналогичный но по нему больше информации.

Суть в том что когда например элемент списка(View) проскролливается и исчезает вверху, он появляется внизу и в этом View отображаются данные другого элемента, а вы например размер изменили.

Собственно для решения проблемы нужно внести информацию о шрифте в ваш массив с исходными данными, и на `onBindViewHolder()` его соответственно применять.

Comment: Заработало! Большое спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Если вопрос решен - пометте его решенным, слева от него есть галочка.

Answer (score 1):

У вас такая лажа происходит, потому что вы храните значения размера текста в ViewHolder-е, этого делать никак нельзя, т.к. вы там накликаете одно, а он потом использует эти ссылки для других элементов списка и это же значение тоже, вот поэтому и косяк.

можете использовать анонимный класс для обработчика нажатия и добавить его в методе **onBindViewHolder()** для нужного вам TexView и всё будет отлично